# if flag=0 , get data from xml with php

Tags: php, xml

Hey guys i'm new in php.
Firstly i have a loop which get the data from the xml file.
Inside the loop i want to create an if condition which will have a flag=0 and when $item['description'] is the same for second time ( flag = 1 ) then stop and continue for the other.
Any help will be appreciated :D

```
 foreach ($item_array as $item) {
            $flag=0;
            if ( make_safe($item['diamerisma']) == $_GET['diamerisma'] ) {
              if ( $item['description'] == $item['description'] && flag == 0 ) {
            $html .= '<ul data-role="listview" id="weatherList" data-theme="b" data-insert="true" >';
            $html .= '<li><div id="Left1"><a href="main.php?description=Kiklades">' . make_safe( $item['description'] ) . '</a></div></li>';
            $html .= '</ul>';
            echo '</dd>';
            $flag=1;
              }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the xml code

```
    <item>
        <title>Alexan</title>
        <description>Ioannina</description>
        <diamerisma>Ipeiros</diamerisma>
        <metar>1009</metar>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Center</title>
        <description>Ioannina</description>
        <diamerisma>Ipeiros</diamerisma>
        <metar>1010</metar>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Tzoumerka</title>
        <description>Ioannina</description>
        <diamerisma>Ipeiros</diamerisma>
        <metar>1011</metar>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Center</title>
        <description>Igoumenitsa</description>
        <diamerisma>Ipeiros</diamerisma>
        <metar>1012</metar>
    </item>
<item>
        <title>Paramithia</title>
        <description>Igoumenitsa</description>
        <diamerisma>Ipeiros</diamerisma>
        <metar>1013</metar>
    </item>
<item>
        <title>Arta</title>
        <description>Arta</description>
        <diamerisma>Ipeiros</diamerisma>
        <metar>1014</metar>
    </item>
```

Now the code displays Ioannina , Ioannina , Ioannina , Igoumenitsa , Igoumenitsa ,  Arta and i would 
like to display : Ioannina , Igoumenitsa ,  Arta

Comment: As beautiful as Greek is, could you possibly translate the text so we can read your code more easily?

Comment: Hope is better now larsAnders !

Comment: You have already stored the XML data into the array `$item_array`? Since you're only using `$item['description']` it will be easy to manipulate the array to unique `description` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some comments: you can jump to next interation of a loop as foreach typing `continue`, if you set `$flag = 0` inside foreach loop it will always be 0 when you check it. And ALWAYS $item['description'] will be equal to $item['description']

My advice is put used values in an array just like this:

```
$used_values = array();
foreach ($item_array as $item) {
    if ( make_safe($item['diamerisma']) == $_GET['diamerisma'] ) {
        if (!in_array($item['description'], $used_values) ) {//This will check if this value hasn't been listed yet
            $html .= '<ul data-role="listview" id="weatherList" data-theme="b" data-insert="true" >';
            $html .= '<li><div id="Left1"><a href="main.php?description=Kiklades">' . make_safe( $item['description'] ) . '</a></div></li>';
            $html .= '</ul>';
            $html .= '</dd>';
            $used_values[] = $item['description'];//here you preserve used values for avoiding repetition
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $processed=array();

    foreach ($item_array as $item) {

    if ( ! in_array( $item['diamerisma'], $processed ) ) //if diamerisma not in processed array
          {
                if ( make_safe($item['diamerisma']) == $_GET['diamerisma'] )

                {

                $html .= '<ul data-role="listview" id="weatherList" data-theme="b" data-insert="true" >';
                $html .= '<li><div id="Left1"><a href="main.php?description=Kiklades">' . make_safe( $item['description'] ) . '</a></div></li>';
                $html .= '</ul>';
                echo '</dd>'; 
                $processed[] = $item['diamerisma']; //add diamerisma to processed array

                }  

          }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to have the $flat initiated outside of the loop and when it is greater than 1, `break` out of the loop. The break statement jumps you out of a control statement, or more.

```
$flag=0;
foreach ($item_array as $item) {
  if ( make_safe($item['diamerisma']) == $_GET['diamerisma'] ) {
    if ( $item['description'] == $item['description']) {
      $html .= '<ul data-role="listview" id="weatherList" data-theme="b" data-insert="true" >';
      $html .= '<li><div id="Left1"><a href="main.php?description=Kiklades">' . make_safe( $item['description'] ) . '</a></div></li>';
      $html .= '</ul>';
      echo '</dd>';
      $flag += 1;
    }
  }
  if ($flag > 1) {
    break;
  }
}
```

see the documents here:

http://php.net/break